# Flutter Realtime push notification working in app running but app close, socket also closed

Tags: flutter, dart

I was tried to implement realtime push notification using django websocket and client side i was used web_socket_channel and local notification package.it's working in app running. But not running app closed.

Websocket need to run in app background, so I tried work manager but that time socket not running. Any other way to solve this problem in flutter.

Comment: You can Integrate the firebase_messaging package in your Flutter app for handling Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

Comment: FCM is good, but we are planned to use own socket channel using django.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.